# What is the null hypothesis and p value in the lagged autocorrelation of innovations in Kaman filter

Tags: p-value, autocorrelation, statsmodels, kalman-filter

I am using `statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acf` to calculate the lagged autocorrelation of innovations in Kalman filter with `alpha=0.05`. Innovation is defined as `observation - observed equivalent of model forecast`. And I want to calculate the lagged autocorrelation of the time series of innovations, to see whether autocorrelation lags at 1,...,10 time steps are zero. So that I would know whether my Kalman Filter is optimal.

I used `statsmodels.tsa.stattools.acf` to calculate the autocorrelation. But I don't know what does it mean by the p value it returns? and what is the corresponding null hypothesis? what if the p-value returned is very small? say if I set `nlags=10`, i.e. to calculate the autocorrelation of 10 time steps lag, the result is `acf[10] = 0.219018`, and its p-value is `1.544171e-218`.

I knew p value is the probability that we accept the null hypothesis. But I don't know what is the hypothesis over here.